# Content per page is not changing

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I'm having a problem in my PHP Code,
I want to display my data from database into 10 data per page (pagination),
But the content per page is not changing, please help me to edit this code and work correctly. Big

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_display"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select databse.
//$uid= $_GET['uid'];
$connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if (isset($_GET["uid"])) { $uid  = $_GET["uid"]; } else { $uid=1; }; 
$start_from = ($uid-1) * 10; 

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE board_id ='5' ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT $start_from, 10" ;
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$connection); 

?>

<table width="980" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="contact-list">
 <colgroup>
<col width="20">
<col width="150">
<col width="250">
<col width="90">
<col width="90">
<col width="80">
<col width="80">
 </colgroup>
 <tr>
<th>번호</th>
<th>이름</th>
<th>내용</th>
<th>메일</th>
<th>연락처</th>
<th>연락처</th>
<th>글삭제</th>
</tr>
<?php
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result)) { 
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['uid']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['member_display']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['content']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
<td><a href="" onclick="return confirm('삭제 하시겠습니까?');">글삭제</a></td>
</tr>

<?php

// close while loop 
}

?>
</table>


<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl_name WHERE board_id ='5' "; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records /10); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='http://daeheung.webgd.gethompy.com/?page_id=96=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}
?>


<?php
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();?>
```

Comment: What is the error you facing ?

Comment: The content per page is not changing but there's no error displayed.the content is not looping.

Comment: Yes you are using `SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE board_id ='5' ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT $start_from, 10"` which will display the list. You want to do pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look there is nothing wrong with selecting content but with pagination links
You writing simething like that

```
echo "<a href='http://daeheung.webgd.gethompy.com/?page_id=96=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
```

And trying to find page number like that

```
if (isset($_GET["uid"])) { $uid  = $_GET["uid"]; } else { $uid=1; };
```

But there is no parameter uid in your link. I think you wanted to write something like

```
echo "<a href='http://daeheung.webgd.gethompy.com/?page_id=96&uid=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
```

Comment: Glad to help you. You can mark my answer as accepted to say thanks. There is an article what to do if someone answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers